# Uploading a large file to Office 365 via CSOM PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office-365, file-upload, csom

I have the following code :

```
$FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream

$FileCreationInfo.URL = $File

$Upload = $DestinationFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$Context.Load($Upload)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$ListItem = $Upload.ListItemAllFields;
$Listitem["Modified"] = $ModDateSP
$Listitem["Created"] = $DateSP
$Listitem["Author"] = $author  
$Listitem["Editor"] = $lastSaved  

$ListItem.Update()
$Context.Load($Upload)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Which uploads a small file correctly and then changes the meta data of the file in SharePoint.

The problem I face is when I try to upload a file that is 500MB it times out with the message

> Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"

after around 3min.
Is there a different way I could upload the file and still be able to change the meta data, or even increase the timeout time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint CSOM request size is very limited and it cannot excess 2 MB limit and you cannot change this setting in Office 365 environment. 
So if you have to upload bigger files you have to use REST API. Here is MSDN reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx

Comment: can you give any help on uploading via the REST API via powershell?

Comment: I found this sample how to achieve this: https://gist.github.com/vgrem/10713514 and more info in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393075/file-upload-to-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api

Answer (score 4):

If you are following Office Dev PnP, then they have released brilliant approaches for uploading files of various size. Their code is in c#, which we convert into PowerShell.

I had an exactly same scenario where I needed to upload files of size greater than 500MB or 1GB and then update the metadata properties. I used PowerShell csom for this.

Office Dev PnP has mentioned 4 types of methods, I will let you know about 2. And ask you to read in detail about [Large file upload with CSOM at GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/dev/Samples/Core.LargeFileUpload) and [Upload large files sample app for SharePoint at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn904536.aspx)

1. **SaveBinaryDirect**: There is no file size limitations, but there's a security time-out after 30 minutes. Only use this method if you’re using a user-only authentication policy. User-only authentication policy is not available in an app for SharePoint, but can be used in native device apps, Windows PowerShell, and Windows console applications.

   ```
   $Context.RequestTimeout = [System.Threading.Timeout]::Infinite
   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::SaveBinaryDirect($Context, $fileUrl, $LocalFile.OpenRead(), $true)
   ```

   > **Note**: Initially I was using this method without setting Request Timeout to infinite which worked for files of size around 100MB but
   >   threw `Timeout error` for files of size 500MB. So I made sure I use
   >   Request Timeout as Infinite.
2. **Upload file in chunks**: Upload a single file as a set of chunks using the `StartUpload`, `ContinueUpload`, and `FinishUpload` methods on the File class. There is no file size limits. Time-out occurs after 30 minutes. Each chunk of the file must upload within 30 minutes of completion of the previous chunk to avoid the time-out. Recommended for SharePoint Online when the file is larger than 10 MB.

   Office Dev PnP has given this function in c#, I have simply converted it into PowerShell

   ```
   Function UploadFileInSlice ($ctx, $libraryName, $fileName, $fileChunkSizeInMB) {
       $fileChunkSizeInMB = 9

       # Each sliced upload requires a unique ID.
       $UploadId = [GUID]::NewGuid()

       # Get the name of the file.
       $UniqueFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($fileName)

       # Get the folder to upload into. 
       $Docs = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($libraryName)
       $ctx.Load($Docs)
       $ctx.Load($Docs.RootFolder)
       $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

       # Get the information about the folder that will hold the file.
       $ServerRelativeUrlOfRootFolder = $Docs.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl

       # File object.
       [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File] $upload

       # Calculate block size in bytes.
       $BlockSize = $fileChunkSizeInMB * 1024 * 1024

       # Get the size of the file.
       $FileSize = (Get-Item $fileName).length
       if ($FileSize -le $BlockSize)
       {
           # Use regular approach.
           $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($fileName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
           $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
           $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
           $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
           $FileCreationInfo.URL = $UniqueFileName
           $Upload = $Docs.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
           $ctx.Load($Upload)
           $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
           return $Upload
       }
       else
       {
           # Use large file upload approach.
           $BytesUploaded = $null
           $Fs = $null
           Try {
               $Fs = [System.IO.File]::Open($fileName, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)
               $br = New-Object System.IO.BinaryReader($Fs)
               $buffer = New-Object System.Byte[]($BlockSize)
               $lastBuffer = $null
               $fileoffset = 0
               $totalBytesRead = 0
               $bytesRead
               $first = $true
               $last = $false

               # Read data from file system in blocks. 
               while(($bytesRead = $br.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0) {
                   $totalBytesRead = $totalBytesRead + $bytesRead

                   # You've reached the end of the file.
                   if($totalBytesRead -eq $FileSize) {
                       $last = $true
                       # Copy to a new buffer that has the correct size.
                       $lastBuffer = New-Object System.Byte[]($bytesRead)
                       [array]::Copy($buffer, 0, $lastBuffer, 0, $bytesRead)
                   }

                   If($first)
                   {
                       $ContentStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
                       # Add an empty file.
                       $fileInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
                       $fileInfo.ContentStream = $ContentStream
                       $fileInfo.Url = $UniqueFileName
                       $fileInfo.Overwrite = $true
                       $Upload = $Docs.RootFolder.Files.Add($fileInfo)
                       $ctx.Load($Upload)

                       # Start upload by uploading the first slice.
                       $s = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($buffer) 

                       # Call the start upload method on the first slice.
                       $BytesUploaded = $Upload.StartUpload($UploadId, $s)
                       $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

                       # fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added.
                       $fileoffset = $BytesUploaded.Value

                       # You can only start the upload once.
                       $first = $false
                   }
                   Else
                   {
                       # Get a reference to your file.
                       $Upload = $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($Docs.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + [System.IO.Path]::AltDirectorySeparatorChar + $UniqueFileName);
                       If($last) {
                           # Is this the last slice of data?
                           $s = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($lastBuffer)

                           # End sliced upload by calling FinishUpload.
                           $Upload = $Upload.FinishUpload($UploadId, $fileoffset, $s)
                           $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

                           Write-Host "File upload complete"
                           # Return the file object for the uploaded file.
                           return $Upload
                       }
                       else {
                           $s = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($buffer)

                           # Continue sliced upload.
                           $BytesUploaded = $Upload.ContinueUpload($UploadId, $fileoffset, $s)
                           $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

                           # Update fileoffset for the next slice.
                           $fileoffset = $BytesUploaded.Value
                       }
                   }

               }  #// while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
           }
           Catch {
               Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
           }
           Finally {
               if ($Fs -ne $null)
               {
                   $Fs.Dispose()
               }
           }
       }
       return $null
   }
   ```

   **Usage**:

   ```
   $credentials = Get-Credential
   $SiteURL = "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com"
   $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL) 
   $Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credentials.UserName, $credentials.Password)

   $UpFile = UploadFileInSlice -ctx $Context -libraryName "YourLibName" -fileName "C:\LargeFiles\FileWithLargeSize.docx"
   ```

   Check this [blog](https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2016/02/26/large-file-upload-in-sharepoint-online-with-csom-powershell/)

So once you finish uploading the files using any of the above method, then you can load the file object and change the metedata properties.

```
$File = $Context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($fileUrl)
$ListItem = $File.ListItemAllFields
$Listitem["Field"] = "Value"
$ListItem.Update()
$Context.Load($ListItem)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```